# at what level modprobe operates ? - linux

Tags: linux, kernel, blacklist, kernel-modules, modprobe

I have a machine with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, i have the need for blacklisting a module, i have blacklisted it in `blacklist.conf` but nothing happened; i have solved my problem passing `modprobe.blacklist=<module>` as argument to the GRUB command line.

My question is: when and how modprobe operates ? it's clear to me that it doesn't really operates 1:1 with the kernel because my kernel still loads even the blacklisted modules, so what is the role of modprobe ? And more than that, on what level, during the boot time, it operates ?

Answer (score 1):

Linux kernel follows modular kernel design. Loadable Kernel Modules (LKM) are object files that contain code to extend the running kernel, or so-called base kernel. LKM's are typically used to add support for new hardware, filesystems etc.

According man page of modprobe.d, you must create files in /etc/modprobe.d directory which end with the .conf extension specify those options as required.
 They can also be used to create convenient aliases: alternate names for a module, or they can override the normal modprobe behavior altogether for those with special requirements (such as inserting more than one module).

But if you want to initiate modprobe at boot or otherwise - then /etc/modprobe.d cannot work. You need udev or rc.sysinit or systemd, etc.